# dynamically detect the return type in typescript

Tags: typescript

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZWwAtgBbTOAbwCg44BzYGAFQE8xgBnAHgCUA+ABQBKAFxxeAbmoBfatVCRYiFGiy4CCUgFcANphjRuzOKFRIAJpzicYUZPX5VacGJnrjm0up2JlM4oQk5NJy1NgQSLZwmNowRAAM+Fp6BtCBKfqGUNwARLHxCblOALzOdG4ecPlxibkANC6+wQHldAxMbBycIm3tcFBM2lBIff3tSJikwOIA5ABGEPOz9XAu4+3+CLpz87rawAACqCAwAHQRpLPr43IbMt7td3ByD9RAA) and here is the code:

```
export interface Schema {
  getTypes<R>(): R;
}

export interface Simulator<T extends string> {
  tag: T;
  schema: Schema;
}

const auth0Simulator: Simulator<"auth0"> = {
  tag: "auth0",
  schema: {
    getTypes() {
      return {
          name: 'bob', 
          email: 'blue@text.com'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I get this error:

> Type '() => { name: string; email: string; }' is not assignable to type '() => R'.
> Type '{ name: string; email: string; }' is not assignable to type 'R'.
> 'R' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ name: string; email: string; }'.(2322)
> input.tsx(2, 3): The expected type comes from property 'getTypes' which is declared here on type 'Schema'

I understand the error but is there anything I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First, the problem is in the generic of the function. If you want Typescript to recognize the type correctly you should add it to the interface declaration like so:

```
export interface Schema<R> {
   getTypes(): R;
}
```

The Simulator would then look like this:

```
export interface Simulator<T extends string, R> {
    tag: T;
    schema: Schema<R>;
}
```

And its implementation with type definition like this:

```
const auth0Simulator: Simulator<"auth0", User> = {
    tag: "auth0",
    schema: {
        getTypes() {
          return {
              name: 'bob', 
              email: 'blue@text.com'
          }
        }
    }
}

type User = {
    name: string;
    email: string;
}
```